# receiving error "no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ifstream&, int&, char)'"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, getline

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct subscriberName
{
   string first;
   string last;
   int custID;
};

struct address
{
   string address2;
   string city;
   string state;
   int zipcode;
};

struct date
{
   string month;
   int day;
   int year;
};

struct renewal_information
{
   int monthsLeft;
   date da;
};

struct subscriberInfo
{
   subscriberName si;
   address ad;
   renewal_information ri;
};


int main()
{
   void OpenFileIn(ifstream& FileIn, string& FilenameIn);
   void OpenFileOut(ofstream& FileOut, string& FilenameOut);
   bool ProcessCustInfo(bool& truth, ifstream& FileIn);
   void OutputCustInfo(ifstream& FileIn, ofstream& FileOut);

   ifstream FileIn;
   ofstream FileOut;
   string FilenameIn;
   string FilenameOut;
   bool truth;
   subscriberInfo si;


   OpenFileIn(FileIn, FilenameIn);

   OpenFileOut(FileOut, FilenameOut);

   ProcessCustInfo(truth, FileIn);

   OutputCustInfo(FileIn, FileOut);
   return 0;
}

bool ProcessCustInfo(bool& truth, ifstream& FileIn, subscriberInfo& si)
{
   getline(FileIn, si.sn.first, '\n');                   //here
   getline(FileIn, si.sn.last, '\n');
   getline(FileIn, si.sn.custID, '\n');
   getline(FileIn, si.ad.address2, '\n');
   getline(FileIn, si.ad.city, '\n');
   getline(FileIn, si.ad.state, '\n');
   getline(FileIn, si.ad.zipcode, '\n');
   getline(FileIn, si.ri.monthsLeft '\n');        //to here




}



void OutputCustInfo(ifstream& FileIn, ofstream& FileOut, subscriberInfo& si)
{
   if(si.ri.monthsLeft=0)                     //here down to
   {
      FileOut << string(55,'*') << endl;
      FileOut << si.sn.first << " " << si.sn.last << "(" << si.sn.custID << ")" << endl;
      FileOut << sn.ad.address2 << endl;
      FileOut << sn.ad.city << ", " << sn.ad.state <<sn.ad.zipcode << endl;
      FileOut << "The last renewal notice was sent on " <<sn.ri.da.month << " " << sn.ri.da.day << ", " << sn.ri.da.year << endl;          //here
      FileOut << string(55,'*') << endl;
   }
}
```

I can't figure out what is causing this error. It occurs in the first function where all the getline calls are. The compiler is specifically calling out the third, fifth, and last one, but I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with all of them.

Comment: `geline()` only accepts a `string&` as a second parameter, you need to place it in a string then convert it to an `int` or other type. Since some of the members of your structs are of type `int`

Comment: @JohnMarkCaguicla would it be easier to change the members to strings? What problems could that cause?

Comment: It depends on how are you going to use them, if you're just displaying them it would be fine to change them to `string`, but for more practical purposes you may, for example, use `custID` as an `int` to pass to a function. In that case just retrieve it as a `string`, then convert it to an `int`.

Comment: You could simply use and overload the insertion and extraction operators for ofstream and ifstream. They do automatic conversion of types.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a variable of type `int` to `getline` in:

```
getline(FileIn, si.sn.custID, '\n');
```

That's a problem.

Use:

```
std::string custID;
getline(FileIn, custID, '\n');
si.sn.custID = std::stoi(custID);
```

You have same problem with:

```
getline(FileIn, si.ad.zipcode, '\n');
```

and

```
getline(FileIn, si.ri.monthsLeft '\n');
```

Also, the line

```
if(si.ri.monthsLeft=0)
```

is wrong. I suspect it is a typo. You need to use `==` instead of `=`

```
if(si.ri.monthsLeft == 0)
```

Comment: yes thank you. What exactly does the `std::stoi(custID);` do?

Comment: @LCro, it converts a string to an integer. You can see more details at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol.

Comment: Also, I can only have 3 parameters `bool`, how can I get `custID`, `zipcode`, and `monthsLeft` to be apart of that scope?

Comment: @LCro, I didn't understand that.

Comment: sorry, I can only have 3 parameters per function. I'm getting a compiler error again saying that `custID`, `zipcode`, and `monthsLeft` are not declared in the scope of the function. How can I fix that?

Comment: @LCro, I suggested a solution for `custID`. If that doesn't work, you might have made an error in using my suggestion. If that works, you can use the same method for the other two variables.

Comment: I didn't simply put `string custID;` but it's saying now that `stoi` is not apart of the scope? I'm thoroughly confused.

Comment: @LCro, `std::stoi` is supported only in C++11. If you are using g++, you can use the flag `-std=c++11` to enable C++11 features.